# Can I Use State inside filter function ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

```
class ConsultantsImage extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstIndex: 0,
            numConsult:2,
            consultsImages:[],
            filterImages:[]
        }

        this.getConsultantsImages();
        this.showConsultantImages();
        this.previousConsultant = this.previousConsultant.bind(this);
        this.nextConsultant = this.nextConsultant.bind(this);

    }
    getConsultantsImages(){
        let consultsImages = []

        this.props.images.map((consultantImage,index) =>
            consultsImages.push(<ConsultImage key={index} image={consultantImage} />)
        )

        this.state = {consultsImages:consultsImages}
    }
    nextConsultant(){
        if(this.props.images.length > this.state.firstIndex ){
            this.setState({firstIndex:this.state.firstIndex++})
        }



    }
    previousConsultant(){
        if(this.state.firstIndex >0) {
            this.setState({firstIndex: this.state.firstIndex--})
        }
    }
    showConsultantImages(){
      this.state.filterImages=this.state.consultsImages.filter((consultImage,index)=> index<this.state.numConsult)
    }

    render(){


        return(

            <Row>
                <i className="icon-arrow-left icons font-2xl d-block mt-4"></i>
                {this.state.filterImages}
                <i className="icon-arrow-right font-2xl d-block mt-4"></i>
            </Row>
        )
    }
}

export default ConsultantsImage;
```

> i want to know about how to use react state in filter function.

this is the code snip i used

```
this.state.filterImages=this.state.consultsImages.filter((consultImage,index)=> index< this.state.numConsult)
```

Comment: `this.state` gives you access to state.

Comment: Your `getConsultantsImages()` and `showConsultantImages()` methods should not update the state directly. Depending on what you want, you can either return a filtered array without assignment or use the `setState()` method to update the state.

Comment: They way you are accessing state in filter is right, but you are directly mutating state at places which you shouldn't do. Also there is not need to filter at all, since you are only filtering based on index

Answer (score 1):

Since `showConsultantImages` and `getConsultantsImages` are only called from the constructor and used to set state array, you can simply return from the array and set to state directly. Also since you are filtering based on index only, all you need to do is use `splice/slice`

```
class ConsultantsImage extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstIndex: 0,
            numConsult:2,
            consultsImages: this.getConsultantsImages();,
            filterImages:[]
        }

        this.previousConsultant = this.previousConsultant.bind(this);
        this.nextConsultant = this.nextConsultant.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
         this.showConsultantImages();
    }
    getConsultantsImages(){
        let consultsImages = []

        this.props.images.map((consultantImage,index) =>
            consultsImages.push(<ConsultImage key={index} image={consultantImage} />)
        )

        return consultsImages
    }
    nextConsultant(){
        if(this.props.images.length > this.state.firstIndex ){
            this.setState({firstIndex:this.state.firstIndex++})
        }



    }
    previousConsultant(){
        if(this.state.firstIndex >0) {
            this.setState({firstIndex: this.state.firstIndex--})
        }
    }
    showConsultantImages(){
        this.setState(prev => (
             {
                 filterImages: prev.consultsImages.slice(0, this.state.numConsult)
              }
        ));
    }

    render(){
        return(

            <Row>
                <i className="icon-arrow-left icons font-2xl d-block mt-4"></i>
                {this.state.filterImages}
                <i className="icon-arrow-right font-2xl d-block mt-4"></i>
            </Row>
        )
    }
}

export default ConsultantsImage;
```

Comment: showConsultantImages() call in constructor therefor setState method show error

Comment: i explain my problem again can you help

Comment: say i have a 10 array images it is pass as props this component. when component load should show first 4 images. then i have a next and previous button when i click privios button i want to show 1,2,3,4 images again i press next button i want to show 2,3,4,5 images

Comment: Where do you get an error. also which functions are called on next and previous button

Comment: this is the

 error Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Comment: This is not an error, but a warning. Move this.showConsultantImages(); to componentDidMount function and it will go away

Comment: Glad it helped,,

Comment: sorry have a problem slice array should contain 2 image but its contain all images

Comment: Can you print this.state. numConsult in showConsultantImages function and also the this.state.filterImages in setState callback